# Replacing variable without quotes in R Markdown SQL Chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using a [sql chunk](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html#sql) chunk and using `?parameter` in my query to substitute variables like:

````
```{sql}
Select * from some_table where some_column = ?parameter 
```
````

However, I want to be able to use the parameter to template a query instead eg:

````
```{r}
template_query <- "with template_table AS (Select * from another_table)"
```

```{sql}
?template_query

Select * from template_table
```
````

However, the template_query gets replaced as a complete string instead. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The function `glue_sql` from tidyverse's [glue](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/) package solved my problem:

````
```{r}
template_query <- glue_sql("with template_table AS (Select * from another_table)")
```

```{sql}
?template_query

Select * from template_table
```
````